# Codeigniter connection to host (a database error)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pdo

I got this error when I was uploading my files to my host server, particularly when I started uploading my models.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> Filename: controllers/Arena.php
>
> Line Number: 13

I am using codeigniter as the php framework and 000webhost.com for my free hosting needs.

example of my model

```
<?php
class Image_model extends CI_Model{

    function get_image_data(){
        $this->load->database();

        $this->db->select('nuotrauka,id,kalba');
        $this->db->where('kalba', 'lt');
        $query = $this->db->get('events');

        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

my controller

```
<?php
class Arena extends MY_Controller{

    public function display(){

        $this->load->model('Image_model');
        $data['images'] = $this->Image_model->get_image_data();

        $this->load->view('includes/head');
        $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
}
```

and my database.php

```
    $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'  => 'mysql:host=files.000webhost.com; dbname=id692581_name; charset=utf8;',
    'hostname' => 'files.000webhost.com',
    'username' => 'id692581_username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'id692581_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I'm sitting on this error for the second day and it is making me crazy

Comment: and now you SHALL at once go and change the database username and password if those are the actual ones.

Comment: I would autoload the database in config/autoload.php saves you putting         `$this->load->database();` every where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used 000webhost before just change `'hostname' => 'files.000webhost.com',`
to the ip in phpmyadmin
what i mean go to phpMyAdmin and copy the ip in page in paste it like this:
`'hostname' => '164.50.60.70',`

OR do this 
You have go to our members' area, enter the control panel and click on the 'MySQL' icon. Your MySQL hostname will be listed there.

**Important!** Never use 'localhost' as your MySQL hostname here or you will get access denied errors!

Comment: Sorry instructions not very clear there is no members area nor control panel and definitely no mysql icon(i've never seen mysql words used in this website to begin with)

Comment: It seems I cant find anything so I'll just use localhost this time

Comment: i am trying to connect but hostname is giving error

Comment: from where I get hostname, i m using free account @Abanoub Makram